# What is the package of R function trim()?

Tags: r

I am getting the following error in my R program running on RStudio:

> "Error:could not find function "trim""

This is a Shiny application that calls a function that calls another program. The program has been imported into the server function with:

```
source("Utilities/utilities.R", chdir = TRUE)
```

This program uses the R function `trim()`.  I have been looking for the package of this function without success. Could anyone tell me in what package the function `trim()` is found? I am not sure if that package is installed in my environment and if it's not, that might be the reason why the program cannot find the function `trim()`.

Thank you.

Comment: Try typing `??trim`. This will search all installed packages (not just attached packages) for functions containing `trim`. From that you can figure out which one makes the most sense in your context. In my R, I see `glue::trim` and `lava::trim`

Comment: I have my own function `trim` that I loaf from my `.Rprofile`,  and when I call `getAnywhere(trim)` I see that I have 5 other namespaces loaded with it as well: `R6,
ggplot2,
data.table,
jsonlite,
glue`. You should learn to use `traceback()` so you can figure out what function is calling `trim`.

Comment: When i disable the utilities. R program by commenting #source("Utilities/utilities.R", chdir = TRUE), the problem persists, what makes me think it might not have to do with the function trim.  I have found this problem several times and have been able to solve it by clearing the workspace and starting a new session.  But this time does not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: My first try would be to see if loading `ggplot2` solves it.  I don't really like that version of trim since it basically throws away the ends of long character strings without warning, but my guess is that `shiny` programmers would typically have that namespace loaded. My version of trim looks very much like the `data.table` version. You might get better debugging messages from Rstudio if you made this into a package.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `sos` R package and search for `trim`:

```
# install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
results <- findFn("trim")
```

It gives a lot of results, but the list is more comprehensive than doing `??trim`.

You can also filter out results where the actual function name is not `trim` by running the following command:

`filtered_results <- results[results$Function == 'trim']`

Then you can view the resulting data frame and see a list of the different packages containing a function called `trim`.